# .Net 7 Mixed Identity and JWT

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, asp.net-identity

I'm attempting to use the ASP.net Identity (7.0.5) along with JWT on .Net 7. For the most part I have things working. I can register/login/etc using Identity via the browser, and JWT tokens get created and validated correctly when using Postman.

The problem is that when the JWT token is invalid/expired the application is redirecting via 302 to the Login page. The end result is that instead of a 401 Unauthorized, we end up with a 200 OK with the body of the login page. This will make it difficult for the client app to know they need to obtain a new JWT token.

When I disable redirects in Postman, the WWW-Authenticate header is containing the correct error reason: **Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token expired at '04/17/2023 20:16:59'"**

When I strip out all of the Identity stuff from my application, it correctly returns the same error, along with 401 unauthorized and no redirects.

This is what the relevant parts of my Program.cs file look like:

```
var services = builder.Services;

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser<int>,IdentityRole<int>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
    cfg.LoginPath = "/Accounts/Login";
    cfg.LogoutPath = "/Accounts/Logout";
    cfg.AccessDeniedPath = "/Accounts/AccessDenied";
    cfg.SlidingExpiration = true;
    cfg.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
    cfg.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    cfg.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    cfg.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
    cfg.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});

services.AddAuthentication(cfg =>
{
    cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultSignOutScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        cfg.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"]!)),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = configuration["Jwt:Audience"]
        };
        cfg.Validate();
    });

services.AddAuthorization(cfg =>
{
    var policyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
    policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    cfg.DefaultPolicy = policyBuilder.Build();
});

/* ... */

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapRazorPages();
```

I included the `app.Use...` stuff because the order they are included in the pipeline is relevant. Any thoughts on what we're missing?

---

Edit: Looking at the source of `services.AddIdentity<,>()` [on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), it looks like it is calling `AddAuthentication()` and setting the default schemes to be Identity cookie based. I'm not sure what the effect of doing another `services.AddAuthentication()` is? It doesn't appear to be overriding the defaults.